# Div not showing background-color in chrome

Tags: css, background-color

I'm working on a little assignment right now and the page only displays correctly in IE. None of the `div` `background-color`s are showing up.

HTML

```
<body bgcolor="#949191">
  <div id="heading">
    <div id="banner">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="Crown Awards" style="border-style: none"/>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#heading{
  height:100px;
  width:900px;
  background-color:"#FFFFFF";
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;            
  display:block;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  position:relative;
}
#banner{
  width:415px;
  float:left;
  padding:20px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#nav{
  width:400px;
  float:right;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  background-color:"#003399";
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;  
}

#content{
  width:900px;
  background-color:"#FFFFFF";
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;            
  display:block;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}    
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
li {
  display:inline;
  float:right;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}
a {
  display:block;
}
```

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

IE

[image: IE]

Comment: What are the double quotes for when defining background colors? try background-color: #ffffff; without ""

Comment: `image/icon` is [no longer experimental](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988), drop the `x-` prefix.

Comment: Ozkan- Can't believe I didn't catch that! That's exactly what it was! Thank you very much!
Quentin- I will be sure to do that. I guess that's what I get for copy and pasting a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent element collapses if the child elements are floated.

A quick fix for this is to add the css `overflow:hidden` to the parent which will clear the floats and retain the desired height of the children.

Also the `background-color` css shouldn't have quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Floating elements do not, by default, influence the height of their parent element. Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent element to change that.

CSS colour codes should not be quoted. Remove the quote characters and [use a validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

The background colour shows up in IE due two of the many bugs that appear in Quirks mode. Avoid them by triggering standards mode with a suitable Doctype. Start your HTML with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
background-color: #003399;
```

without "